# Constructor not defined during Test

Tags: java, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I am having a pesky error testing this piece of code.Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tested standard controllers before but not the getSelectedMethod
**Error:
Constructor not defined:[myClass].(ApexPages.StandardController)**

```
public class MyClass{

  public List<Web__c> postings {get;set;}
  public static final String POSTINGSTATUS = 'Yes';

  public MyClass (ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
     List<Web__c> selectedWeb = (List<Web__c>) controller.getSelected();
     postings = [Select Id, Name,
                    FROM Web___c Where Id IN: selectedWeb
                    AND Date__c != null 
                    AND Date__c > today];
 }
}
```

My Test Class

```
private class myTestClass {

  static testMethod void WebTest() {
    List <Web__c> posting = helper.createWeb(4);
    insert posting;

    Test.startTest();  
    PageReference pageRef = Page.VFPAGE;
    Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
    ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(posting[0]);
    myClass JPC = new myClass(sc);
    sc.setSelected(posting);
    Test.stopTest();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`new ApexPages.standardController(posting[0])` looks wrong to me.

It should likely be `new ApexPages.StandardSetController(posting[0])` if you want to create a new instance of `ApexPages.StandardSetController`, or just `ApexPages.standardController(posting[0])` (without the `new`) if it's a static method that returns such an instance.

BTW: you should state what error you get and where in the code it occurs when asking such a question, as figuring it out without that information is pretty hard. I just found this by chance, I'd asked for that information otherwise.